# How to save a photo using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, image, camera

I am developing a software using html, javascript and php. It is supposed to save pictures using a webcam and then saving them into a database.

The thing is, it takes the pictures with no problem, but I actually can't figure out how to save the pictures to a file, and which format would be more efficient to save it into the MySql DB.

Here's how I am taking the pictures:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
     //Este objeto guardará algunos datos sobre la cámara
     window.datosVideo = {
     'StreamVideo': null,
     'url' : null
     };
     jQuery('#botonFoto').on('click', function(e){
          var oCamara,
          oFoto,
          oContexto,
          w, h;

          oCamara = jQuery('#videoElement');
          oFoto = jQuery('#foto');
          w = oCamara.width();
          h = oCamara.height();
          oFoto.attr({'width': w, 'height': h});
          oContexto = oFoto[0].getContext('2d');
          oContexto.drawImage(oCamara[0], 0, 0, w, h);
           });
} );
```

The code takes the picture and draws it in the variable, which is a canvas

Comment: You can get base64 image from canvas right?

Answer (score 1):

It can be done by the following procedure:

**HTML:**

```
<canvas id="foto"></canvas>
<form action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="img" id="img_val">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

**JS:**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var c = document.getElementById("foto");
    document.getElementById("img_val").value = c.toDataURL();
 </script>
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) : 
        $data = $_POST['img'];

        list($type, $data) = explode(';', $data);
        list(, $data)      = explode(',', $data);
        $data = base64_decode($data);

        file_put_contents('uploads/image.png', $data); 

    endif; 
?>
```

**What's going here?**

*Firstly* I added a `form` below the `canvas` to store image in *base64 encoded format* in a hidden `input` field.

*Secondly* `JS` script get content from `canvas` and stores it in `base64 encoded format` into the `hidden input` field.

Now when the user submits the form to upload image the data will be send to the server containing `image` in encoded format.

*Thirdly* `PHP` code remove the *data:image/png;base64,* and `decode` back the recieved data to store image with proper content into the server.

It may be helpful to you to understand how to send an image to the server.